# Android "A Call is in Progress" notification issue

Tags: android, video, notifications, twilio, chat

I created a chat application that uses Twilio Sdk. Everything works fine but after a Video Call ends, I get this notification which doesn't go away whatever I try to do. After this notification appears, if I try to initiate Video Call, it doesn't work then. Maybe its using some of my resources like microphone which does not allow the app to start Video Calling because the Android system shows that microphone is still being used. Also this is appearing on my Redmi 9C. I have already searched everywhere on the net but no such solution found. It also states its a bug in some devices but there must be something that can be done to resolve this. Help would be appreciated thank you.[image]

This is the code that is used to disconnect from a room:

```
private fun killAllVideoProcess() {
        if (localVideoTrack != null) {
            if (localParticipant != null) {
                localParticipant!!.unpublishTrack(localVideoTrack!!)
            }

            localVideoTrack!!.release()
            localVideoTrack = null
        }

        if (room != null && room!!.state != Room.State.DISCONNECTED) {
            room!!.disconnect()
            disconnectedFromOnDestroy = true
        }

        if (localAudioTrack != null) {
            localAudioTrack!!.release()
            localAudioTrack = null
        }
        if (localVideoTrack != null) {
            localVideoTrack!!.release()
            localVideoTrack = null
        }
}//killAllVideoProcess ends
```

Comment: What is the code you are using when you disconnect from a room?

Comment: I have updated my question please look into it

Comment: That looks like you are stopping the tracks and releasing the resources. I'm comparing to the Twilio Video Android quick start, where [you can see the disconnect function here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/blob/master/quickstart/src/main/java/com/twilio/video/quickstart/activity/VideoActivity.java#L345-L375). It is also resets the volume control stream to the original stream and stops an audioSwitch. Do you need to do either of those things too?

Comment: I havent used AudioSwitch nor am I setting the volumen control stream to the original stream. Do you think this could be the reason to the issue?

Comment: If I were you, I’d compare against how the Twilio example apps work. I’m not an Android developer myself, so I can’t guide much better than that, but if that’s a difference between what your app is doing and the sample apps, then it might be causing this issue.

Comment: Yeah that comparison and contrast is side by side and things are pretty much the same. Will need to look deeper as to the root cause of this. 
Thanks though :)

Comment: Good luck, sorry I can't be of more help!